# SQL COUNT() function and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, left-join

I have two tables, users and departments. I want to have table, where are two columns: first is department name, second is count - how many users are assigned to this department.
And I have this piece of code:

```
SELECT department_name as 'deptName', 
       COUNT(users.department_id) as 'userCount' 
FROM departments
LEFT OUTER JOIN users
ON departments.id = users.department_id 
GROUP BY 'deptName'
```

Department's table columns are:

```
 integer id PK

 varchar(20) department_name
```

User's table columns are:

```
 integer id PK

 varchar(20) name

 varchar(20) surname

 int department_id FK
```

**But it does not work.**

Now I have 2 departments, and output should be 2 rows, first with count 8 and second with count 1. **But I see only one row, with all count  (9).**
I use MySQL installed with XAMPP.

Comment: Can you provide sample data set to test @[*fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT department_name as 'deptName',
       COUNT(users.department_id) as 'userCount'
  FROM departments
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users
    ON departments.id = users.department_id
 GROUP BY `deptName`
```

Notice the tick marks vs. your single quotes in the GROUP BY (this is the key to the left of the 1 on your keyboard). Refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

You could also just group by department_name  (the field itself, rather than the alias)

Currently you are grouping on the literal value 'deptName', not the field that you've given an alias of deptName, which is why you only have 1 row returned. You're not actually doing any grouping.

Comment: When I changed single quotes to double, and use department_name instead 'dept_name' it works perfectly :) Thank you :)
But if I use "dept_name", I think that it should work - should it?

Comment: In the group by clause use the tick marks as shown in my edit, or the name of the field (department_name). I would use the name of the name of the field instead of the alias as it's easier and doesn't vary by database, should you ever use a database other than MySQL. In the GROUP BY I believe you will have to use tick marks if you use the alias.

Comment: Version after your edit also works perfectly, I completely forgot about " ` " for MySQL, really thank you.

Comment: When I say tick mark I mean the key above the tab key and to the left of the number 1 on your keyboard, not a single quote. For the select list you can use either a tick mark, single quote, or double quote, for the alias, but for the GROUP BY you have to use a tick mark, a single quote or double quote with the alias won't work. However you could abandon the alias altogether and use just the field name. Also aliases in the select list don't need any tickmarks or quotes if you don't care about cap sensitivity and avoid leading numbers.

Comment: @Pneumokok no problem, if you're all set please mark this as the answer